# What are Kafka transactions?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-transactions-api

What do transactions mean in Kafka? Of course I know the ordinary SQL transactions: `A transaction is a sequence of operations performed (using one or more SQL statements) on a database as a single logical unit of work`

So does it mean it's possible to send something to Kafka, and if something going wrong it will be rolled back (erase messages from partitions?)
And is it possible to write to different topics in a transaction?

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Transactional Producer allows to send data to multiple partitions and guarantees all these writes are either committed or discarded. This is done by grouping multiple calls to [`send()`](http://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord-) (and optionally [`sendOffsetsToTransaction()`](http://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#sendOffsetsToTransaction-java.util.Map-java.lang.String-)) into a transaction.

Once a transaction is started, you can call [`commitTransaction()`](http://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#commitTransaction--) or [`abortTransaction()`](http://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#abortTransaction--) to complete it.

Consumers configured with `isolation.level=read_committed` will not receive messages from aborted transactions.

For more details, check the [Message Delivery Semantics section](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#semantics) in the docs